# How to setup a MS SQL BI development environment on local machine

Tags: ssis

We need to setup a local development machine (with BIDS) to develop SSIS packages as we do not want to install BIDS on the database server itself.

Is there any guides on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a guide to doing this for sql 2008:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1807